# After rebasing my github fork, commits from others are in my pull request

Tags: git, github, conflict, rebase

I have created a github fork and made some changes, then created a pull request. After some revisions, I made some additional changes and rebased my fork (and then also my local copy), then committed and pushed it again.

Now my pull request contains plenty of changes of other people as well:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/14505/files

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it? I only changed 3 files (pandas/io/json.py, pandas/io/tests/json/test_json_norm.py and doc/source/whatsnew/v0.18.1.txt (where I also resolved some conflicts after my rebase).

Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm using pycharm and TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

You made your PR directly from the master branch (which is supposed to reflect the `upstream/master` branch, and not include other changes)

> and how can I fix it

Make sure you have a remote named `upstream` referencing the original repo (the one you have forked)

```
git remote -v
# if needed
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
```

Then create a branch from `upstream/master`

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b myPR upstream/master
```

Finally, cherry-pick the commits representing your changes

```
git cherry-pick myFirstCommit..myCurrentCommit
```

And create a PR from that branch (that you can later on update as you did, but with a rebase on top of `upstream/master`)

[After discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127402/discussion-between-nickpick-and-vonc), the missing step was `git fetch upstream`: the OP was working only with `master` or `origin/master` but those don't matter here: when doing a PR, only `upstream/master` (the main branch of the original repo) is important, and your PR must be rebased on top of it.

Comment: And I would then never rebase my pr, but only my upstream?

Comment: @nickpick you would absolutely rebase your pr branch, on top of upstream/master.

Comment: but why wouldn't the changes of the others then not propagate back to my pr and I would have the same problem again?

Comment: @nickpick no you won't: your PR will be updated with only your pr-branch commit, because if will be based on a recent updated upstream/master.

Comment: Great, that worked. The remote upstream was available. Looks like when I create a new branche in intellij/pycharm it is linked to origin/master instead of upstream/master, which makes things much more complicated. Will need to do it manually in the future

Comment: I create a new pull request and it was fine at first, but then tried to merge the 4 commits into one and do a rebase, now I'm having again other people's commits in my push. How is this possible? Why was there no warning? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/14583

Comment: @nickpick that might actually be expected (I mean, it is not as before, where you had *a lot* of commits from other people) Here you only have one which does not belong to you. Check your branch *before* rebasing (is it composed only of your commits?) and after.

Comment: So there's no way to avoid this contamination? I would have though that a rebase puts all my commits on top of the other changes?

Comment: @nickpick yes, which is why I suggested to check your local commit in your local PR branch before the rebase (`rebase upstream/master`, followed by `git push --force`): it should only include your commits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127402/discussion-between-nickpick-and-vonc).